# Suggestion on avoiding same word multiple times in Resume writing

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing my resume and don't want to repeat same word multiple times in a small paragraph of profile section. Currently my write up is below:

> With 7 years’ experience in the software implementation with **strong background** in health care industry, I’ve written code, automate things and tested them with  flexible and analytical skills with a keen eye for details. After working in India and the UK I believe a true diversified culture with **strong work ethics** can fulfill business requirement in more balanced way and I’m in a search for the same. Besides my professional career I like to keep myself busy with some practice design and development work and few of them are available at my portfolio on GitHub.

Any suggestions on modifying the highlighted areas?

I'm not fond of **solid background** or **solid foundation** and I believe **strong work ethics** sounds better.

Comment: You could use a thesaurus to find suitable synonyms.

Comment: @Mick - That was my first thought, too, but most synonyms for "strong" (like _forceful, powerful, indestructible, ardent, fierce,_ and _intense_) don't work very well in this context.

Comment: A firm background? An excelent backgroung?

Comment: A *solid background*, perhaps, and *positive work ethics*?

Comment: What @Mick said. See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+a+solid+background+in%2Chas+a+strong+background+in%2Chas+a+firm+background+in%2Chas+an+excellent+background+in&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20a%20solid%20background%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20a%20strong%20background%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chas%20an%20excellent%20background%20in%3B%2Cc0) for relative prevalence of *strong, solid, excellent, firm* in OP's context (but actually the last of those is so unlikely it doesn't even appear on the chart! :)

Comment: @Mick and Others. Thanks for your quick replies. I checked dictionaries and thesaurus prior posting here but most of them didn't look good to me. I'm quite impressed by the below answer but only the **with** is repeated.

Answer (score 3):

> With 7 years’ experience in the software implementation **with most of my experience being in** in **the** health care industry, I’ve written code,
>   **automated** things and tested them with flexible and analytical skills with a keen eye for details. After **having worked** in India
>   and the UK I believe a true diversified culture with **a** strong work
>   **ethic** can fulfill business requirement in more balanced way and I’m **looking for these qualities in turn**. Besides my professional
>   career I like to keep myself busy with some practice design and
>   development work and few of them are available at my portfolio on
>   GitHub.

This is how I would state that paragraph. It doesn't repeat too many things and has a bit more complicated sentence structure.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'm glad that you made correction quite a few areas of my write up and enhanced the same. Only the **with** is getting repeated here. But I guess that's not bad English. What you do say?

Comment: @Anup No not at all!

Comment: How about `With 7 years’ experience in the software implementation with most of it being in the healthcare industry, I’ve written code, automated things and tested them with flexible and analytical skills with a keen eye for details.` just omitted multiple uses of experience.

Comment: That looks good.